How would I change the colour of the background of a cell based on the set days past
I've had a look at implementing the following:
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "txtContent": "@currentField",
    "style": {
       "background-color": "=if(@currentField <= @now + 2592000000, 'red', if(@currentField <= @now + 1209600000, 'orange', if(@currentField >= @now - 86400000, 'Green', '')))"
    }
}

If its over 4 weeks I would like to colour the background Red, if over 2 weeks, Orange and any added today, to green. I would also like to set the text colour to white.
they are all red though, so not sure what I am doing wrong.
This is for TEAMS Lists.
Thanks

See if this works for you:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField<=(@now -(86400000 *4 * 7)), 'red', if(@currentField >(@now -(86400000 *4 * 7))  && @currentField < (@now -(86400000 *2 * 7)), 'orange', 'green'))",
    "color": "white",
    "font-size": "1.5em",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "justify-content": "center"
  }
}



Calculated Column Formula for [Diff-In-Days]
=DATEDIF(MyTestDate,TODAY(),"d")



Thank you so much Matiur, that seems to work perfectly! I spent hours trying to work that out!
